# jQuery - .off() not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently writing a program in JS using jQuery, which is basically a checkers game.

I am using jQuery's `.on()` and `.off()` functions to create events for each of the pieces. What happens is that the program will loop through each of the pieces and will set a function to be called when the piece is clicked. This function will then show the player the available moves that the piece can make.

This is setup using a for-loop and this code:

`$("#" + String(playerPositions[i])).on('click', function() {movePiece(validMoves, this)});`

This passes the valid moves of that piece as well as the id of that piece to the `movePiece` function which then deals with highlighting the moves.

The problem lies in my "clean up" function, where I want to remove the onClick handler from all the pieces once a move is made. I use this code:

`var elements = $('.' + classToClean);
  //clean off the onclick
  elements.off("click"); <-- this doesn't work
  //clean off the classes
  elements.removeClass(classToClean);`

The strange thing is that a) the `.removeClass` function works perfectly, and b) the onClick attribute only is removed from the piece that I have just moved.

I have tried using attaching an empty function to the piece, but this did not work. I also cannot use `$('.validPieces').on('click', function () ... )` because I need to pass variables unique to the piece with each piece's onclick.

Thanks in advance for any help, and I apologise about the wall of text but I wanted to make sure everything was clear.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.off('click')` should remove all event handlers of that type. If that doesn't work it is likely the element(s) you are removing from don't match the ones they were attached to.

If that removes more than you want, you will need to include a reference to your handler in the `.off()` call. To preserve the different `validMoves` variable for each call you will need to use a closure:

```
function move(validMoves) {
  return function() {
    movePiece(validMoves, this);
  }
}

// within your for loop
keepMoveFn[i] = move(validMoves);
$("#" + String(playerPositions[i])).on('click', keepMoveFn[i] );

// elsewhere in your code:
  //clean off the onclicks
  keepMoveFn.forEach(function(fn) { 
    el.off("click", fn );
  }
```

Note that you will need to either keep a reference to the move function or have access to it when you call the `.off()` function. In the snippet above I assume you are keeping an array of functions that you can then later iterate to remove the click events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my issue with this is that the `validMoves` variable is different for each piece in the for loop and therefore I think I am forced to use my anonymous function. Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: *"You will need to include a reference to your handler in the `.off()` call:"* No, calling `.off("click")` will remove **all** jQuery-installed click handlers on the elements in question.

Comment: @demar - definitely worth investigating why your `.off("click")` isn't working. But to answer your question in prior comment, I've updated my edit to give more detail on targeting specific handlers.